# Google Glass Emulator Camera support

Tags: google-glass

I am going to work with Google glass device for my final year project.For this I need to access Camera view but I don't have a real device.I suppose to do this with emulator.Is there Google glass emulator to testing camera view.I need to clear this before starting of my project.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is no Google Glass emulator I'm aware of.
That being said, you could simply use the regular emulator with a camera on your desktop (or even your device). APIs are the same, you just have to keep in mind that the resolution is smaller, as well as the CPU capacities comparing to a real mobile device.